# sub-invariant functions for a conservative ergodic measure preserving transformation

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I have been reading some papers in Infinite Ergodic theory, and I think that the following fact is a standard argument in the subject, but I have not been able to figure out why it is true. I will state it in the form that I need it, so some hypothesis could be not necessary.

Let $(X,\mathbb{B},\mu,T)$ be a $\sigma-$finite measure space equipped with a $\mu-$invariant transformation $\sigma:X\to X$. We also suppose that the transformation $\sigma$ is conservative and ergodic. The for a measurable function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$, if $f(Tx)\geq f(x)$ for every $x$, then $f$ is constant a.e.

Maybe if I can get that $f(Tx)\leq f(x)$ then by ergodicity it would follow that $f$ is constant a.e., but I do not know how to prove that inequality. Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $T$ in your question the same as $\sigma$?

Comment: If this is the case and the transform is non-singular. I think the following equivalent condition of conservative and ergodic can help: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_A(T^nx)=\infty$ a.e. for any $A$ of positive measure.

Comment: @SimingTu To the first question, yes, I just fixed the typo. I also can assume that $T$ is non-singular so I do have that condition, but don't see how could it help.

Comment: You can prove that a transformation is ergodic if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(T^nx)=\infty$, a.e. for any $f$ non-negative, measurable and $\int_Xf d\mu>0$. Then you can apply this to $f(Tx)-f(x)$ to get that its integration must be 0.